# Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())

Tags: django

I am creating a blog using Django.I want to fetch my post from the database using Queryset by using command `Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())`

But I am getting blank output. I have already imported timezone using
`from django.utils import timezone`

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots. Copy and paste the text/ What does your `Post` model look like? What do you get if you loop through all the posts and print their published date: `for post in Post.objects.all(): print(post.published_date)`

Comment: Have a look at this page-https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/ In this page by creating a new user using command->>> Post.objects.create(author=me, title='Sample title', text='Test') , I've created 4 posts. Now I want to show these 4 posts by using this filter- Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()) But after using this command,not a single post is being shown up. what should i do? I had attached a screenshot of my command line. The required result is highlited in that screenshot..please see that for the refrence.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments, [edit] your original question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

This filter will not return any posts where `published_date` is `None`.

The [tutorial](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_orm/) gives instructions how to publish a post.

```
>>> post = Post.objects.get(title="Sample title")
>>> post.publish()
```

This will set `published_date` for that post, so now that post should be returned if you re-run the filter command.

```
>>> Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

It is showing empty because your command is asking for the published post and yet no post is published.

Try this:

```
post = Post.objects.get(title="Sample title") #Sample title is the name of the title
post.publish()
Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now())

<QuerySet [<Post: Sample title>]>
```

Hope it helps.